# Repeat a vector in 4 dimensions without using repmat

Tags: matlab

I have to repeat a vector in 4 dimensions and I used the repmat function to do this, but it is taking a big amount of time. So, how I implement this without using repmat?

Here is an example of the code I'm using.

```
A = rand(1, 240); %The vector I want to replicate

B = repmat(A, 240, 1, 180, 3); %Here I get a matrix of size 240 240 180 3
```

Here is the function where I'm calling the repmat. The function basically implements a three nested sum:

```
function gr = g_transformation3(f, c, delta)
%f --> image to be transformed
%c --> control points matrix
%delta --> spacing in pixels, between the control points

[X, Y, Z] = size(f);
%[n, m] = size(c);

x0 = 0:(X - 1);
y0 = 0:(Y - 1);
z0 = 0:(Z - 1);

x1 = delta:(X + delta - 1);
y1 = delta:(Y + delta - 1);
z1 = delta:(Z + delta - 1);

x2 = (2*delta):(X + 2*delta - 1);
y2 = (2*delta):(Y + 2*delta - 1);
z2 = (2*delta):(Z + 2*delta - 1);

x3 = (3*delta):(X + 3*delta - 1);
y3 = (3*delta):(Y + 3*delta - 1);
z3 = (3*delta):(Z + 3*delta - 1);

i0 = floor(x0./delta) + 1;
j0 = floor(y0./delta) + 1;
k0 = floor(z0./delta) + 1;

i1 = floor(x1./delta) + 1;
j1 = floor(y1./delta) + 1;
k1 = floor(z1./delta) + 1;

i2 = floor(x2./delta) + 1;
j2 = floor(y2./delta) + 1;
k2 = floor(z2./delta) + 1;

i3 = floor(x3./delta) + 1;
j3 = floor(y3./delta) + 1;
k3 = floor(z3./delta) + 1;

u = x0./delta - floor(x0./delta);
v = y0./delta - floor(y0./delta);
w = z0./delta - floor(z0./delta);

Bu = zeros(4, numel(u));
Bv = zeros(4, numel(v));
Bw = zeros(4, numel(w));

%Computing the vector of B-splines
Bu(1, :) = ((1 - u).^3)/6;
Bu(2, :) = (3*u.^3 - 6*u.^2 + 4)/6;
Bu(3, :) = (-3*u.^3 + 3*u.^2 + 3*u + 1)/6;
Bu(4, :) = (u.^3)/6;

Bv(1, :) = ((1 - v).^3)/6;
Bv(2, :) = (3*v.^3 - 6*v.^2 + 4)/6;
Bv(3, :) = (-3*v.^3 + 3*v.^2 + 3*v + 1)/6;
Bv(4, :) = (v.^3)/6;

Bw(1, :) = ((1 - w).^3)/6;
Bw(2, :) = (3*w.^3 - 6*w.^2 + 4)/6;
Bw(3, :) = (-3*w.^3 + 3*w.^2 + 3*w + 1)/6;
Bw(4, :) = (w.^3)/6;

T00 = repmat(Bu(1, :)', 1, Y, Z, 3).*(repmat(Bv(1, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j0, k0, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(2, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j1, k0, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(3, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j2, k0, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(4, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j3, k0, :));

T01 = repmat(Bu(2, :)', 1, Y, Z, 3).*(repmat(Bv(1, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i1, j0, k0, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(2, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i1, j1, k0, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(3, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i1, j2, k0, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(4, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i1, j3, k0, :));

T02 = repmat(Bu(3, :)', 1, Y, Z, 3).*(repmat(Bv(1, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i2, j0, k0, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(2, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i2, j1, k0, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(3, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i2, j2, k0, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(4, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i2, j3, k0, :));

T03 = repmat(Bu(4, :)', 1, Y, Z, 3).*(repmat(Bv(1, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i3, j0, k0, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(2, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i3, j1, k0, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(3, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i3, j2, k0, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(4, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i3, j3, k0, :));

matr = reshape(Bw(1, :), [1 1 Z]);
T0 = repmat(matr, X, X, 1, 3).*(T00 + T01 + T02 + T03);

clear T00 T01 T02 T03;

T10 = repmat(Bu(1, :)', 1, Y, Z, 3).*(repmat(Bv(1, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j0, k1, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(2, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j1, k1, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(3, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j2, k1, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(4, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j3, k1, :));

T11 = repmat(Bu(2, :)', 1, Y, Z, 3).*(repmat(Bv(1, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i1, j0, k1, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(2, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i1, j1, k1, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(3, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i1, j2, k1, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(4, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i1, j3, k1, :));

T12 = repmat(Bu(3, :)', 1, Y, Z, 3).*(repmat(Bv(1, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i2, j0, k1, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(2, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i2, j1, k1, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(3, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i2, j2, k1, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(4, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i2, j3, k1, :));

T13 = repmat(Bu(4, :)', 1, Y, Z, 3).*(repmat(Bv(1, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i3, j0, k1, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(2, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i3, j1, k1, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(3, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i3, j2, k1, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(4, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i3, j3, k1, :));

matr = reshape(Bw(2, :), [1 1 Z]);
T1 = repmat(matr, X, X, 1, 3).*(T10 + T11 + T12 + T13);

clear T10 T11 T12 T13;

T20 = repmat(Bu(1, :)', 1, Y, Z, 3).*(repmat(Bv(1, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j0, k2, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(2, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j1, k2, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(3, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j2, k2, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(4, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j3, k2, :));

T21 = repmat(Bu(2, :)', 1, Y, Z, 3).*(repmat(Bv(1, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i1, j0, k2, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(2, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i1, j1, k2, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(3, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i1, j2, k2, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(4, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i1, j3, k2, :));

T22 = repmat(Bu(3, :)', 1, Y, Z, 3).*(repmat(Bv(1, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i2, j0, k2, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(2, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i2, j1, k2, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(3, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i2, j2, k2, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(4, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i2, j3, k2, :));

T23 = repmat(Bu(4, :)', 1, Y, Z, 3).*(repmat(Bv(1, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i3, j0, k2, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(2, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i3, j1, k2, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(3, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i3, j2, k2, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(4, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i3, j3, k2, :));                              

matr = reshape(Bw(3, :), [1 1 Z]);
T2 = repmat(matr, X, X, 1, 3).*(T20 + T21 + T22 + T23);

clear T20 T21 T22 T23;

T30 = repmat(Bu(1, :)', 1, Y, Z, 3).*(repmat(Bv(1, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j0, k3, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(2, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j1, k3, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(3, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j2, k3, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(4, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j3, k3, :));

T31 = repmat(Bu(2, :)', 1, Y, Z, 3).*(repmat(Bv(1, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i1, j0, k3, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(2, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i1, j1, k3, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(3, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i1, j2, k3, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(4, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i1, j3, k3, :));

T32 = repmat(Bu(3, :)', 1, Y, Z, 3).*(repmat(Bv(1, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i2, j0, k3, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(2, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i2, j1, k3, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(3, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i2, j2, k3, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(4, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i2, j3, k3, :));

T33 = repmat(Bu(4, :)', 1, Y, Z, 3).*(repmat(Bv(1, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i3, j0, k3, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(2, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i3, j1, k3, :) + ... 
                                  repmat(Bv(3, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i3, j2, k3, :) + ...
                                  repmat(Bv(4, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i3, j3, k3, :));

matr = reshape(Bw(4, :), [1 1 Z]);
T3 = repmat(matr, X, X, 1, 3).*(T30 + T31 + T32 + T33);

clear T30 T31 T32 T33;

gr = T0 + T1 + T2 + T3;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Define "big amount of time"? I don't think this is an expensive operation, and you won't find any faster options. However, you might not need to use `repmat` at all, depending on what you intend to do with the output. Note that MATLAB has had `bsxfun` for 10+ years, and since a few years its functionality is implicit in all element-wise operators and quite a few other functions too. `repmat` is usually not necessary any more.

Comment: The problem is that I have to call repmat lots of times per call of function, so the function needs to be call about 12000 times, and the amount of repmat calls is making the function take 12 seconds to run.

I've read about the bsxfun, but I don't know how to use it in this problem yet...

Comment: Share how you use the replicated matrix, we might be able to help you speed up the function. You won't be able to speed up `repmat`, its speed is mostly bound by memory writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about direct element-wise operation? With the lastest Matlab versions it does all the sizing for you:

```
B = repmat(A, 240, 1, 180, 3);  % Elapsed time is 0.264423 seconds.
C = A.*ones(240,1,180,3);       % Elapsed time is 0.027216 seconds.
```

*Disclaimer*: times have been measured with R2019a on a laptop with `tic` and `toc`, so you are likely to obtain different values, and even a different ratio. However I think the time difference is significant enough to give it a try.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me a lot.

Comment: Would `A + zeros(240,1,180,3)` be faster? In any case, I doubt that the function call overhead of `repmat` is that large. Did you "warm up" the function? Please use `timeit` to time these operations: `timeit(@()repmat(A, 240, 1, 180, 3))` vs `timeit(@()A.*ones(240,1,180,3))`.

Comment: Using `timeit` on MATLAB Online I see 0.0326 s for `repmat`, and 0.0373 for the alternative. So this suggestion is ~15% slower. The first time you run a function like `repmat`, it needs to be loaded. The second time you run it, it's a lot faster. The time difference you see is the time it takes to load and parse the function.

Answer (score 2):

If you have MATLAB R2016b or later, you can implement all those operations directly without any `repmat` calls at all:

```
T00 = repmat(Bu(1, :)', 1, Y, Z, 3).*(repmat(Bv(1, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j0, k0, :) + ...
                                      repmat(Bv(2, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j1, k0, :) + ... 
                                      repmat(Bv(3, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j2, k0, :) + ...
                                      repmat(Bv(4, :), X, 1, Z, 3).*c(i0, j3, k0, :));
```

is the same as

```
T00 = Bu(1, :).' .* (Bv(1, :) .* c(i0, j0, k0, :) + ...
                     Bv(2, :) .* c(i0, j1, k0, :) + ... 
                     Bv(3, :) .* c(i0, j2, k0, :) + ...
                     Bv(4, :) .* c(i0, j3, k0, :));
```

If you have an older version of MATLAB, you can use `bsxfun` to implement each of those operators. This will look a lot more ugly, though.

---

Note that I replaced `'` by `.'`. The former is the complex conjugate transpose, which is likely not what you intend to use. To change the orientation of a vector, you should always prefer `.'`. For real-valued matrices they are the same, but getting used to the correct operator will prevent lots of hard-to-find errors if you ever work with complex data in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ran the code and It was hugely improved. Thank you very much.